# Tracking anothe iphone on Mapview

Tags: iphone

I want to developed iphone application in which i want to track another iphone on google map with in 10km region what kind of API can i use please tell me

Thanks

Comment: CoreLocation will be needed for sure, and possibly GameKit for connecting the users.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the device you're tracking to tell you its position. That means that it'll have to be running some app (possibly the same app) to get its position using Core Location. Then, it'll have to provide that information. As Richard Ross points out in his comment, you could do that using GameKit. Another approach would be to have the device send its location to a server that you create, perhaps using a web service. Your device would then query the server to find out the location(s) of device(s) it cares about.